# Writing specific parts of the file to another file

Tags: fortran

I am writing a code to read huge file (File XYZ) which has a couple of objects (say A,B,C,D,E... there might be more and each object has hundreds of data files). Now I need to read the file into Fortran and select an object for example 'object B' and write all the information of 'object B' into a new file which I create using the fortran code.

Each object (from A-....) had information consisting of header files and an array of data (a matrix(i,j) where i varies for each file and j=4 ). I have to read in both the header and array data into the new file and these objects (A-....) are not ordered sequentially (suppose after A may be C or D).

I have written a small code but it doesn't seem to work well as I am either able to output only the header but not the array or nothing at all attaching a data file for an object and code.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
 program trail


   implicit none

    CHARACTER (LEN=5) :: thumb='3C286', SOURCE

    INTEGER :: pair(4), n,io, allocstat


   real, dimension(:,:),allocatable:: a



  CHARACTER (LEN=20) ::  POLCODE, DEC, RA 
  CHARACTER (LEN=40) :: TELESCOPE, NAME_MY, DATA_FILENAME, object , date,  TEXT, HEADER, restfreq,BANDWIDT, TSYS, OBSTIME, ANGLE
  character(len=180) :: Outdat
  character(len=75) :: ra_1, residu, flux, vlafit
  open(2, FILE='trail9.txt',POSITION='APPEND')

do
    open(1, File="column_3C286_iteration1.txt",status='old' )

     read(1,*), SOURCE


 10  if(Source.eq.'OJ287') then

   ! READING THE DATA   

      read(1,'(A40)') DATA_FILENAME
      read(1,'(A40)') TELESCOPE
      read(1,'(A40)') NAME_MY
      read(1,'(A40)') data_filename
      read(1,'(A40)') OBJECT
      read(1,'(A40)') restfreq
      read(1,'(A20)')  polcode
      read(1,'(A40)') angle
      read(1,'(A40)') date
      read(1,'(A40)') bandwidt
      read(1,'(A40)') tsys
      read(1,'(A40)') obstime
      read(1,'(A20)') ra
      read(1,'(A20)') dec
      read(1,'(A40)') text
      read(1,'(A40)')  header
      read(1,'(A180)') OUTDAT
      read(1,"(T2, A3,T30,A4, T50,A6,T67,A6)"),ra_1, residu, flux, vlafit



n=0

  do
    read(1,*,iostat=io) pair
    if (io/=0) exit
    n = n + 1
  end do


allocate(a(n,4),stat=allocstat)

do   i=1,n                                                                                 
    read(1,*)  (a(i,j),j=1,4 )                                              

  enddo 

 if  (index(data_filename,'#')>0 ) then 

!WRITING THE DATA

              write(2,'(A40)')  DATA_FILENAME

             write(2,'(A40)') TELESCOPE
            write(2,'(A40)') NAME_MY
            write(2,'(A40)') data_filename
            write(2,'(A40)') OBJECT
            write(2,'(A40)') restfreq
            write(2,'(A20)')  polcode
            write(2,'(A40)') angle
            write(2,'(A40)') date
            write(2,'(A40)') bandwidt
            write(2,'(A40)') tsys
            write(2,'(A40)') obstime
            write(2,'(A20)') ra
            write(2,'(A20)') dec
            write(2,'(A40)') text
            write(2,'(A40)')  header
                WRITE(2,'(A180)') OUTDAT
 Write(2,"(T2, A3,T30,A4, T50,A6,T67,A6)"),ra_1, residu, flux, vlafit


 do i=1,n

    write(2,"(T1,F10.4: T27,F10.4,T47, F10.4, T63,F10.4, T75,F10.4 )"), (a(i,j), j=1,4)

end do

end do
 end if


end do

end program trail
```

Comment: Well my bad. I actually commented out the command when I loaded it here. Initially i used jump in place of i. Using the above code i end up with a blank output file.

Comment: Hey I tried the above solution but i still end up getting again with a blank file and it still does not give a value of n consistent with what I expect

Comment: Hey yes my code contains many such block of different objects with the same format(header+data lines). I use the gfortran compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try changing the type of `pair` from integer to real and modify the code as

```
real :: pair(4)
integer :: i

n = 0
do
    read(1,*,iostat=io) pair
    if (io/=0) exit
    n = n + 1
end do

do i = 1, n + 1
    backspace( 1 )
enddo
```

In this way, the read statement counts the lines including four floating-point numbers and stops reading when non-numeric characters (such as #) are found in the line. Please note also that `backspace()` is performed n+1 times so that the file pointer goes back to the top of the current data section.

Although not very sure, I also think that the following open statement

```
open(1, File="column_3C286_iteration1.txt",status='old' )
```

should be written before the outermost DO loop if this corresponds to the data file.

To summarize, I suggest the following modification:

```
real :: pair(4)
integer :: i

open(1, File="column_3C286_iteration1.txt",status='old' )

do
    read(1,*,end=5000), SOURCE     

    if( Source .eq.'OJ287' ) then

        ! read the remaining header and data lines in one block.

        read(1,'(A40)') DATA_FILENAME
        read(1,'(A40)') TELESCOPE
        ...
        read(1,"(T2, A3,T30,A4, T50,A6,T67,A6)"),ra_1, residu, flux, vlafit

        n = 0
        do
            read(1,*,iostat=io) pair
            if (io/=0) exit
            n = n + 1
        end do

        do i = 1, n + 1
            backspace( 1 )
        enddo    

        if ( allocated( a ) ) deallocate( a )
        allocate( a( n, 4 ) )

        do i = 1, n
            read( 1, * ) a( i, 1:4 )
        enddo

        !! write out the obtained data to file 2.
    endif
enddo
5000 continue
```

---

**Edit**

If we simply want to copy one block of "header + data" to a different file, it is more straight-forward to echo all the lines in the block without formatting. For example, the program may look like this.

```
character(200) :: str, field
integer :: ios
real :: dum
open( 10, file="input.dat", status="old" )

do
    read( 10, "(a)", end=5000 ) str

    if ( trim(str) == "OJ287" ) then     !! search for the target block

        print "(a)", trim(str)   !! print the tag

        !! read one block.                                                      
        do
            read( 10, "(a)", end=5000 ) str
            read( str, * ) field     !! get the first field of a line

            if ( field(1:1) == "#" .or. field(1:2) == "ra" ) then

                print "(a)", trim(str)  !! header part
            else
                read( str, *, iostat=ios ) dum   !! test if this line starts with a number
                if ( ios == 0 ) then
                    print "(a)", trim(str)  !! data part                        
                else
                    backspace( 10 )
                    exit
                endif
            endif
        enddo

    endif
enddo
5000 continue
```

Comment: Hi , I tried using the above suggestion but i end up with an error                  Fortran runtime error: Bad real number in item 1 of list input

Comment: hey man, Thanks it worked well. the error was probably because the read(1,*,iostat=io) pair(4) should have been included instead of just pair. Thanks a bunch mate.

Comment: It's good to hear that it worked. Btw, are you possibly trying to simply "copy" a selected block (header + data lines) in the file into a different file, using the same format? If so, you can do this in a much simpler way (pls let me know if you are interested in such a code). Cheers :)

Comment: Hey yes i am trying to copy the header+data lines it form one file to another. Could you please tell the simpler way to perform this :). Cheers

Comment: @carltonxavier I have updated the Answer for simply copying a desired block. I first thought that the code would become much simpler, but in fact not that simple... It may be easier to use awk or python etc (ie., not Fortran).